# owl:imports in Fuseki

Tags: owl, fuseki, tdb

I'm new here, and although I've searched for something like this, I couldn't find an answer. So here is my question: How Fuseki handles owl:imports?

Details: I've defined a set of ontologies in different owl files. Let's call two of them of `subDomainA.owl` and `subDomainB.owl.`

To "join" these ontologies, I've defined a single owl file that imports the others. Let's call it `completeDomain.owl`, which owl:imports `subDomainA.owl` and `subDomainB.owl`. There are a few statements explicitly declared in `completeDomain.owl`. If it's not clear, It's something like `sweetAll.owl` in [SWEET](http://sweet.jpl.nasa.gov/ontology/).

I need to import these owl files (with RDF/XML syntax) into TDB using Fuseki. How these imports will be handled? I mean, should I load the `completeDomain.owl` to the default graph and `subDomainA.owl` and `subDomainB.owl` to their respective graphs and Fuseki would "understand" imports and let me query all of them at once?

Using `tdb:unionDefaultGraph` is the same thing? What would happen with the statements declared in `completeDomain.owl` that uses entities declared in the subDomain ontologies? Also, I couldn't see the difference of `tdb:unionDefaultGraph` and [Union Model](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/assembler/assembler-howto.html#union-models).

As you can see, I'm a little bit confused and any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please, see the answer [here](http://answers.semanticweb.com//questions/24294/owlimports-in-fuseki)!

Answer (score 0):

Following the tips from Joshua bellow(thanks for them, by the way), here is the answer:

To organize `owl:imports` into Fuseki, there are 3 options:

1) Import all ontologies files to the default graph.

2) Configure the store using `tdb:unionDefaultGraph` with true value, and import each file to its own named graph. This way, Fuseki will answer a query to the default graph with the union of all named graphs. Also, each graph can be acessed by its named graph and/or `SPARQL GRAPH`.

3) A `Union Model` combines in a single graph other graphs. Any app would not be able to query the graphs separatedely.

The original answer to this question is [here](http://answers.semanticweb.com//questions/24294/owlimports-in-fuseki)!

Comment: It would be nice if you can rework the answer there into an answer here, so that StackOverflow gets an answer too.  At the very least, please be sure to [accept your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (it's fine to accept your own answer) to let other users know that you found a solution, and to help keep the number of questions without an accepted answer down.